# jQuery scrollTop won't let me scroll after executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I have a landing image, that has two functions - one is a click function that once the landing image is clicked it scrolls down to reveal the next section. The second function is a scroll function, where the user scrolls/ swipes down and the scroll is hijacked to the next section. Once one of these functions is activated the landing image is hidden and cannot be seen again until a new tab is opened.

I have the click and scroll function working, the issue is once the scroll effect is finished I cannot resume scrolling the rest of the page.

I realize that the scroll function may still be running which is keeping the scroll at the top, but do not know what to add to my code?

Additionally, I am using the Divi theme, so difficult to add HTML markup

```
 (function ($) {
 $(document).ready(function () {

     let header = $('.cf_bal-header');
     let page = $('html, body');

     // Check for first timers
     if (!sessionStorage.returnVisitor) {

         // No flag, this is the first visit.

         // Set a flag so that next time we know they have been here before.
         sessionStorage.returnVisitor = 'true';

         // Handle Hero image click.
         $('.cf_news_link').click(function () {

             $(page).animate({
                 scrollTop: $(".news").offset().top
             }, 1000);

             return false;
         });

         // Handle scrolling (this is our scroll jacker)
         $(window).on('scroll', function () {

             if ($(page).animate({
                     scrollTop: $(".news").offset().top
                 }, 1000));
             return false;
         });

     } else {

         // Not our first time, hide header.
         header.hide();
     }
 });
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you working in WordPress?

Comment: yes...WordPress using the Divi theme